# Simple HTML should show div in centre of page

Tags: html, css, alignment

Why doesn't this EXTREMELY simple webpage show the div with the id "mainContent" in the centre of the page.

Right now the div is on the left. But I would like the div to be centred in the webpage(body element).

Whats going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> </title>

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        body {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #mainContent {
            width: 800px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #content {
            width: 600px;
            float: left;
            background-color: green;

            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #sidebar {
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
            background-color: yellow;

            overflow: hidden;
        }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mainContent">
        <!-- Left Column/Bar -->
        <div id="content">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Right Column/Bar -->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <p>sidebar</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please mention which browser u render the page

Comment: this may helps u : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/body

Comment: tips: dont use color name, write hex value. it has been deprecated.

Comment: read too : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `margin: 0 auto;` which gives it 0 margin on top and bottom, and automatic margins left and right.

```
    #mainContent {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: @merianos-nikos is right, you should get rid of `text-align: center;` in the body rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
#mainContent {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

try that. `text-align:center` centers text, not necessarily all elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have also to change that:

```
body {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

to that

```
body {
        background-color: red;
    }
```